# Refresh div with gmaps4rails (AJAX)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I'm using Rails 3.0.9 version, and jquery.
I've been using this gem without a database. It is used only for map display, and display KML file on it. For this I used:

```
<div id='ajax_map'>
    <% @kmlurl="http://mysite/file1.kml" %>
    <%= gmaps( :kml => { :data => "[{ url: #{@kmlurl.inspect}}]" } ) %>
</div>
```

All great shows.

I want to do that after you change the links (@ kmlurl), and click on the button, the map updated with this new KML file. I use a separate action js.erb with the following code:

```
$('#ajax_map').html('<%= @kmlurl="http://mysite/file2.kml" %>'+'<br />'+'<%= gmaps( :kml => { :data => "[{ url: #{@kmlurl.inspect}}]" } ) %>');
```

But he does not update the DIV. "js.erb" rendered normally, without using the method of gmaps () it normally returns @ kmlurl. I tested this same code in the ". Html.erb" in the tags , it loads a new file, but, of course, just when the page loads.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem as follows (in js.erb):

```
$('#ajax_map').html('<%= escape_javascript( gmaps({:last_map => false}) ) %>');

Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
Gmaps.load_map = function() {
    Gmaps.map.map_options.maxZoom = 15;
    Gmaps.map.initialize();
Gmaps.map.kml = [{ url: '<%= "#{@kmlurl}" %>'}];
Gmaps.map.create_kml();
    Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
    Gmaps.map.callback();
};
Gmaps.loadMaps();
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would refactor things just a bit.

Say that first bit of code were in your index page.  I'd move the setting of @kmlurl into the corresponding controller action:

```
def index
   @kmlurl = "http://mysite/file1.kml"
end
```

Then (assuming index?)  your index view would be simply:

```
<div id="ajax_map">
  <%= gmaps( :kml => { :data => "[{ url: #{@kmlurl}}]" } ) %>
</div>
```

Then to add a link that will update the map:

```
<%= link_to 'Other Map', '/othermap', :remote=>true %>
```

Now you'd create a route in routes.rb:

```
match '/othermap' => 'foo#othermap'
```

Then in foo_controller.rb:

```
def othermap
  @kmlurl = "http://mysite/file2.kml"
end
```

Then create othermap.js.erb:

```
$('#ajax_map').html(
  '<%= 
    escape_javascript(
      gmaps( :kml => { :data => "[{ url: #{@kmlurl}}]" } )
    )
   %>'
  )
```

That's a quick fix,  but what I would REALLY do is strive to make your view code as simple as possible,  and do all the real work in the controller.  Ideally your view would just be:

```
<div id="ajax_map">
  <%= gmaps( :kml => { :data => @mapdata } ) %>
</div>
```

set up @mapdata as appropriate in your controller.   You've got too much stuff that really belongs in a controller embedded in your view code!  Your othermap.js.erb should be equally simplified. i.e.

```
$('#ajax_map').html('<%= escape_javascript(gmaps( :kml => { :data => @mapdata } ))%>')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the problem remained the same, and nothing essentially has changed. When you click on the link and call "othermap", the map is not displayed. That is not working with a function (gmaps()) call in js.erb.